# Spark: sorting and assigning ids to dataset which has no unique id

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, uniqueidentifier

I have a spark dataset which I get from some Hive table via SQL:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select * from mytable order by myDate");
```

I need to assign unique increasing but not necessary sequential ids to the rows of my dataset sorted by myDate field i.e. assign ids like

> 1,4,6,7,8,9,16 etc

First thing I tried was row_number() function.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select *,row_number() over () as rn from mytable order by myDate");
```

But I failed because myDate is not unique key (**and there are no unique key in my dataset!**), and I faced a very interesting bug. It turned out that each time I modify my dataset...

```
dataset.drop("redundantColumn");
dataset.join(..with something..);
dataset.select("rn","myDate");
```

... the dataset is being recalculated and thus the consequence of row number assignments is different! In other words, because my SQL query is non deterministic, each time I do something with my dataset generated by that query - I get different order of rows and thus different row-to-row_number matches.

Questions:

(1) is it possible to force Spark not to recalculate my dataset each time I do something with it? Indeed, why cant I drop columns or join dataset without re-running the initial query?

(2) any other solutions to this problem? Looks like the only option is to combine monotonic_increasing_id function with row_number and it looks quite verbose:

1. get dataset
2. add column with monotonic_increaing_id
3. create temp view from dataset
4. add row_number while selecting from that temp view

And again, I am not sure Spark will not reassign monotonic_increasing_id during some operations with my dataset like joining and adding columns.

(3) instead of option 2 - is there any way to assign monotonic_increasing_id function aligned with some sorted column?

Comment: Using [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#cache--) will solve problem (1). However, using a window without a partition is discouraged as this will cause all data to be collected on one executor.

Comment: Thank you, werner! Your advice with cache works.